# Timer and saving its state

Tags: windows-phone-7, state, dispatchertimer

I am building a windows phone application (basically its a game but I am not using XNA, Silverlight was enough). The graphics are moving based on a DispatcherTimer. What I want to do is basically stop the timer whenever a call arrives on the phone, and start it again after the call has finished, so that the game state is not lost.

I tried with :

```
    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Game.timer.Start();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
    // This code will not execute when the application is closing
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        Game.timer.Stop();
    }
```

but it did not work, it actually does not reach to this point when a call arrives at the phone. Anyone had such experience?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a call is received you will receieve the [Obscured Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on the Frame.

Please note that this event can also be fired for more than just a received phone call though.